# How to uninstall Pentaho ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall `pentaho` application with a script in the terminal. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to the terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get purge pentaho
```

If you want to create a script to do this for you, simply create a file named deletePentaho.sh or whatever and write in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get purge pentaho
```

Then run :

```
chmod +x deletePentaho.sh
```

to make it executable, and you should be able to run your script:

```
sudo ./deletePentaho.sh
```

Comment: Since the script is running apt-get inside it should be started with `sudo ./deletePentaho.sh`

Comment: Right on, @Videonauth.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed it as given [here](https://akbarahmed.com/2012/05/24/install-pentaho-bi-server-4-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-desktop/) or [here](https://akbarahmed.com/2012/07/19/install-mondrian-3-4-1/) , removing `/opt/Pentaho` should do it.

To do so, execute : `sudo rm -r /opt/Pentaho/`